# pass string as function argument from C to Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, dll, matlab-compiler

I am trying to pass a string as a function argument from c to matlab. In matlab, it searches for a data file with the string name and load the data into a matrix.

```
function bus = new(casefile)
{
   A=loadcase(casefile);
%does additional work on that data aand returns a complex double matrix
}
```

I created the dll for this function using matlab compiler. This is my test code to pass a file name from C to matlab.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "matrix.h"
#include "new.h"


int run_main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    mxArray* casename;
    mxArray* sbus=NULL;

    sbus = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(9, 1, mxCOMPLEX);
    casename = mxCreateString("case9.m");

    if (!newInitialize()) 
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize the library.\n");
        return -2;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Call the library function */

        mlfnew(1, &sbus, casename);
        newTerminate();


        mxDestroyArray(casename);
       
    }
    mclTerminateApplication();
    return 0;
}



int main(int argc, const char** argv)
{
    
    if (!mclInitializeApplication(NULL, 0))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize the application.\n");
        return -1;
    }
    return mclRunMain((mclMainFcnType)run_main, argc, argv);
}
```

It shows this error "loadcase: specified M file does not exist" or "loadcase: specified case not in MATLAB's search path". I tried including the path directory with the file name string. Still shows the same error. The data file and the matlab function is in the same directory. The directory is already included in maatlab path.How to solve this issue?

Comment: If casename is supposed to be the name of a data file, it is unclear to me why you are using a name that ends with m extension which would indicate a MATLAB function code file. Also, what is sbus? What is in new.h? What is the code for mlfnew?

Comment: @JamesTursa case9.m is the name of the  data file from matpower. The file is named with a .m extension. You can find more about it here:
https://matpower.org/docs/ref/matpower5.0/case9.html

sbus is my output from the new function in matlab. I'm calling it from C. I have used matlab compiler to create the dll for new function to call it from C. new.h is the header file of that package.